# find all solutions to $e^{z^2}=i$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do i approach this?

Am I anywhere near right if i do it like this

$$e^{z^2}=i \quad\Rightarrow\quad z^2=\log(i)=\log|i|+i[\pi/2+2 \pi n]$$

and then just take the square root?

The reason for spamming questions today is because I have 4 finals to do within 8 days, I'm studying engineering physics at 150% speed and sometimes its abit too much at once. Thanks for all the help tho, in advance.

Comment: You are taking a good approach.  Remember that $|i| = 1$, so the first part simplifies.

Comment: yes that I am aware of, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's ok. Just remember that $|i|=1$ and that you get *two* square roots for each $n$.

Comment: Maybe I can add something to this question right here. My professor told me that the correct way to do this would be to spilt this problem into two possibilities, the first case where n is non negativ and then another case when n is a negativ number. So i would end up with four answers to complete the whole problem. Do you know how i should do that? He was in a hurry today so he couldn't explain it on the board and my test is tomorrow.